# How to stop each thread at a time in multiple threads in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

What I need to do is creating multiple threads ( eg. 3 threads in example code) and each thread is performing its own computation. After each thread finishes its computation, the corresponding thread should be stopped.

I got the code from [How to stop a thread in Java? Example](http://www.java67.com/2015/07/how-to-stop-thread-in-java-example.html#ixzz4QmDGuiK4)
and it works well for one thread.

However, if I modify this code for multiple threads, then each thread doesn't stop and keeps running. Which means although a thread finishes its doSomeComputation(), it computes again from the beginning instead of stopping it.

I've been googling and searching this website, and tried this and that ( using interrupt, Thread.stop() and so on ). But couldn't find a way I wanted. How to stop each thread, whenever it's own doSomeComputation() is done in each thread?

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import static java.lang.Thread.currentThread;

public class ThreadStopDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        ThreadStopDemo tsd = new ThreadStopDemo();
        tsd.test2();       // NOT stop
        // tsd.test1();    // stop
    }

    // this works well.
    void test1() throws InterruptedException {
        Server myServer = new Server();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(myServer, "T1");
        t1.start();

        System.out.println(currentThread().getName() + " is stopping Server thread");
        myServer.stopThread();
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(200);
        System.out.println(currentThread().getName() + " is finished now");
    }

    // this doesn't stop and keeps running.
    void test2() throws InterruptedException {
        Server[] pool = new Server[3];

        for(int i = 0; i < pool.length; i++) {
            pool[i] = new Server();
            pool[i].start();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < pool.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(currentThread().getName() + " is stopping Server thread");
            pool[i].stopThread();
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(200);
            System.out.println(currentThread().getName() + " is finished now\n");
        }
    }
}

class Server extends Thread {
    private volatile boolean exit = false;

    public void run() {
        while (!exit) {
            System.out.println(currentThread().getName() + " Server is running.....");
            doSomeComputation();
        }
        System.out.println(currentThread().getName() + " Server is stopped....");
    }

    public void stopThread() {
        exit = true;
    }

    void doSomeComputation() {
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The normal method of stopping threads is to call `Thread.interrupt()`, and to have the `run()` code in the thread's `Runnable` to be looping with `while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())`.  Java threads try to play nice, interrupting the thread will request for it to terminate and it's up to you to make sure that the `Runnable` will play nice.

Comment: If they're still running, it just means they're still executing doSomeComputation().

Comment: Why do you have a `while(!exit)` loop in the `run()` method?  If the `run()` method ends the thread ends automatically, so you do not need the while loop if you don't want the computation repeated until cancelled.  If you want the thread to be cancellable then `doSomeComputation()` must check periodically for the cancel flag and return.  You should look at the classes in `java.util.concurrent`, especially `ExecutorService`, `FutureTask` and `ExecutorCompletionService` that provide a useful framework.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to wait for multiple threads is to use [ExecutorService.submit()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)), then call Future.get() to wait for the jobs to complete.